# PSQL command line end changed from => to (>

Tags: postgresql, psql

I tried to execute a query written from \e command, and not now i can't execute any queries but can execute commands in PSQL.

[image: the problem at hand]

And now that i notice this, the commands i typed are in \e now.

[image: state of \e]

The problem starts when i close \e (try to run it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You opened a parenthesis but never closed it, and now `psql` is waiting for the statement to be finished.

Try entering `);` to close the parenthesis (and get an error message).

You can exit `psql` with `\q` if you are completely lost.

Comment: or enter `)\r`  to cancel the input without causing an error.

Answer (score 4):

The psql prompt changes based on what input it is expecting next. The prompt is [actually customisable, as documented here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING), but the default value for `PROMPT2` ("issued when more input is expected during command entry") contains `%R` which is explained as:

> In prompt 2 %R is replaced by a character that depends on why psql expects more input: - if the command simply wasn't terminated yet, but * if there is an unfinished /* ... */ comment, a single quote if there is an unfinished quoted string, a double quote if there is an unfinished quoted identifier, a dollar sign if there is an unfinished dollar-quoted string, or ( if there is an unmatched left parenthesis.

So the `(>` prompt is telling you that somewhere in a query, you opened a `(`, and `psql` is still waiting for the matching `)` before parsing your input.